# Чи доречно вживати питомі відповідники замість запозичених термінів?

Tags: терміни, вживання-слів

Як відомо, більшість термінів - слова іншомовного походження. Не так давно в українську мову почали повертати питомі відповідники на заміну запозиченням. Зокрема в спортивній лексиці: футбол - копанка, волейбол - відбиванка, хокей - гаківка, бокс - стусан (за "Словником спортивної лексики" укл. Осінчук і Левків у 2002 році). Чи доречно їх використовувати?

Comment: -1: Це запитання не демонструє власної спроби автора відповісти на нього, а також воно запрошує до субʼєктивних відповідей, тому що одній особі чи в одних обставинах «недоречно» (як-то в офіційному листуванні), а в інших обставинах — «доречно» (наприклад, з художньою метою, див. персонаж Возного Тетерваковського з «Наталки Полтавки»). Більше подробиць тут: [«Хороші запитання і хороші відповіді»](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5/).

Comment: Мені незрозуміло, чи це запитання про конкретні 4 слова (_копанка_, _відбиванка_, _гаківка_, _стусан_), чи це широке запитання про те, коли треба (чи не треба) використовувати питомі відповідники запозиченим термінам загалом. Якщо друге, то мені знається, питання **занадто** широке. Якщо перше, то слід переформулювати, щоб було зрозуміло, що мова про конкретні слова чи конкретну галузь абощо.

Comment: Я б (якщо це запитання залишиться без змін) подав заявку на його закриття, але не хочу закривати його одноосібно (а технічної можливості ініціювати голосування за закриття в мене, на жаль, нема).

Comment: @Sasha буде тоді двоосібно

Comment: @P.Vovk, я думаю, краще все-таки закрити, ніж вилучати (я undelete'нув і reopen'ув, якщо Ви не проти).

Answer (score 2):

Мені також здається, що на питання досить складно дати об'єктивну відповідь. Врахуємо те, що слова іноземного походження — наслідок географічних, економічних, культурних зв'язків між різними народами, це, так би мовити, складові історії нашої мови (а історія у неї справді багата). Однак, процитую [О. Пономарева](http://ponomariv-kultura-slova.wikidot.com/inshomovna-leksyka):

> Проте запозичати треба лише тоді, коли мова не має власного лексичного
>   позначення для якогось поняття. Часто-густо в усному й писемному
>   спілкуванні мовці вдаються до надуживання чужомовною лексикою через
>   недостатнє знання словесного багатства рідної мови. Чужі слова не
>   загрожуватимуть мові лише тоді, коли, як писав Володимир Самійленко,
>   дотримуватимемося такого принципу — «не цуратися їх (чужих слів. — О.
>   П.), але й не бгати їх у нашу мову без міри».

Особисто я повністю погоджуюся із цією думкою. І гадаю, що, якщо це можливо, то варто шукати відповідники до іншомовних слів, однак, справді інколи це просто не виходить зробити (а особливо це стосується слів пов'язаних із ІТ та різними новітніми технологіями, стравами національних кухонь тощо). Із варіантами вдалих замін можна ознайомитися як і на цьому сайті, так і на [Словотворі](https://slovotvir.org.ua/).

Також ще зацитую висловлення російського письменника Олексія Югова, яке [наводить посібник Міжрегіональної академії управління персоналом «Стилістика ділової мови» Галини Волкотруб (Київ, 2002, ISBN 966-608-195-4) на с. 49](https://labook.com.ua/book_stilistika-dilovo-movi_672/12_-9.-uzhivannya-nshomovnih-slv):

> Чим освіченіша людина, тим глибше вона зобов'язана знати мову свого
>   народу. А отже, і потреба хапатися за іншомовне слівце у того, хто
>   зважується писати статті й книги, має виникати значно рідше, ніж у
>   людини з недостатньою освітою.

Answer (score 0):

<sup>*⅔ відьповідь*</sup>

„[Словник чужомовних слів і термінів](//archive.org/stream/shtepa1977)“ (1977) [Павла Штепи](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%A8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B0):

> бокс — пʼястукарство
>   волейбол — відбиванка
>   гокей — гаківка
>   футбол — копанка

---

Особисто я за чистоту, тому всецїло заохочую вживу, оскільки ранїше цього вживали широко.

> «Слово „гаківка“ могло з'явитися за співзвучністю з оригінальною вимовою слова hockey („га́кі“) і подальшою контамінацією з „гак“ <sup>[[1]](http://www.umoloda.kiev.ua/number/81/118/2312/)</sup>. Низка джерел називає винахідником цього слова І. М. Боберського — одного із засновників організації „Пласт“ <sup>[[2]](//zbruc.eu/node/11419)</sup>».
>
> ---
>
> [Мова про змагання з відбиванки у місті Станіславові, а так Івано-Франківськ називався до приходу совітів у вересні 1939.](//ic.pics.livejournal.com/doniguano/79302469/39402/39402_original.jpg)

---

Родич-запитаня: [Творення української термінології механізмами вторинної номінації. Історія та сьогодення](/q/359/)

Comment: Прошу пояснити відняток, особливо при згадцї _не відповідь_. Зазначу, що то є ½ чи ⅔ відповіддю: віднайшов словник, приклади вживу з минулого і частково теперішнього. Не вистачає тільки суто широке теперішнє.

Comment: "оскільки ранїше цього вживали широко" - а де можна знайти інформацію, наприклад, про те, що замість бокс вживали раніше пʼястукарство?

Comment: @AndriyIvanchenko треба буде пошукати, памʼятаю лише десь вжив __стусани__.

Answer (score -4):

Тут потрібно задавати питання, хто придумував і на якій основі самі відповіднки. Ці, що Ви подали у своєму прикладі, краще не вживати. В мене є підозра, що їх придумали КГБ-ти, адже тільки дибіл може відбиванка, гаківка, стусан вживати)))

Comment: _«Слово „гаківка“ могло з'явитися за співзвучністю з оригінальною вимовою слова hockey („га́кі“) і подальшою контамінацією з „гак“ [(1)](http://www.umoloda.kiev.ua/number/81/118/2312/). Низка джерел називає винахідником цього слова І. М. Боберського — одного із засновників організації „Пласт“ [(2)](http://zbruc.eu/node/11419)»_ ©Вікіпедія. І щодо інших діалектизмів теж так не варто — для мене особисто вони звучать як жарт (впепше чую), але вони мають свою історію. (Хіба що «стусан» в цьому ряді, здається, справді жарт, бо стусан — це 1 удар, а не вид спорту.)

Comment: Але це, звісно, не загальна українська. Це дуже локальні діалектизми. (До загального вжитку їм, здається, дуже далеко.)

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до сайту Ukrainian Language.SE! Наші критерії якості дещо відрізняються від того, що можна побачити на мовних форумах і блоґах. Необґрунтовані відповіді базуються лише на думці їхнього автора і тому викликають хвилю диспутів і заперечень.
А якісні відповіді ґрунтуються на якісних джерелах: словниках, поважних сайтах тощо.
Будь ласка, перегляньте сторінки [tour], [answer] а також
[«Якими мають бути гарні відповіді»](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/5/).
Ви завжди можете виправити відповідь, зробивши її більш аргументованою.
Для цього натисніть [edit].

Comment: «Відбиванка» вживалася на Західній Україні ще до приходу совітів, ось [на цій світлині](https://ic.pics.livejournal.com/doniguano/79302469/39402/39402_original.jpg) йдеться про змагання з відбиванки у місті Станіславові, а так Івано-Франківськ називався до приходу совітів у вересні 1939 р.

Comment: Це не діалектизми, слова взято зі "Словника спортивної лексики", укладеного В.Осінчук, Л.Левків у 2002 році. Дивно, що деякі з них сприймаються як жарт, адже, на мою думку, вони засвідчують багатство українського мовного генофонду. До прикладу, поляки вже давно не використовують запозичених слів на позначення спортивної лексики, у них є питомі відповідники і вони - загальновживані! Наявність власних відповідників до запозичених слів свідчить про самобутність наукової мови. На жаль, нам до цього ще далеко.

Comment: @Анна1989 було б дуже доречно перенести цей коментар у ваше запитання.

Comment: @Анна1989, на мою думку, це була спроба Осінчука і Левків поширити сферу вживання діалектизмів/архаїзмів до рівня загальної лексики. Я не кажу, що це погано — часто саме так і «лікують» мову від іноземного впливу. Але за фактом це наразі не загальновживані слова, і інші джерела, наприклад [«Термінологічний словник зі спортивних ігор» І. Цап і М. Цапа](http://194.44.152.155/elib/local/623.pdf), їх не наводять.

Comment: "Лікування" мови від іноземного впливу називають пуризмом, в українській мові він виникає як відповідь на русифікацію на початку 20 століття. Однак під впливом загальновідомих історичних подій, створену в цей час науково-технічну термінологію вилучають з наукового обігу, вважаючи її самостійницькими проявами. Тому й зараз нам дивно чути такі слова, як відбиванка, кошиківка, хоча ще у 1939 вони були загальновживаними, і були б такими і досі, як у поляків, н-д, якби не репресії. Відновити втрачене нелегко, однак є слова, які з успіхом повертаються до вжитку: летовище, світлина, часопис, руханка.

Comment: @Анна1989, я не впевнений, що в 1939 вони були загальновживаними за межами окремих регіонів.

Comment: На усій території вони й не могли бути загальновживаними, адже Західна Україна ввійшла до складу Радянського Союзу лише у 1939, а східні землі перебували там з 1923. Тому дослідження термінів й ускладнюється історичними процесами і змінами, які були внесені штучно і нав'язані примусово.

Comment: Вточню — не «східні землі» (перебували там з 1923), а більша частина земель, в т.ч. центральні ([ЗУНР порівняно мала](//commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Ukrainian_State_1918.5-11.png)). Чому не могли? Комуністи ж не забороняли кожне окреме слово. Я думаю, ці слова просто не були поширені в інших частинах України до 1923. (Чи поширилися б ці слова із Західної України по всій Україні, якби не було СРСР — невідомо.)

Comment: Скоріш за все "Словника..." немає в інтернеті, про існування цього видання знаю не з мережі.

Comment: @Follower, але 100% слів ніхто не може заборонити. І зазначених у питанні в [«Переліку репресованих слів»](http://www.myslenedrevo.com.ua/uk/Sci/Linguistics/rejestr.html) немає. Так й до самого переліку є запитання (де джерела на кожне слово, можливо, у випадку окремих слів ситуація виявиться неоднозначною, як [ось тут](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/2993)). Мені здається, що «копанка», «відбиванка», «гаківка», «стусан» не поширилися не тому (чи принаймні не лише тому), що хтось заборонив, а через те, що вони від початку мали вузьке ходження.